# C memalloc & mempy give conditional jump valgrind error while splitting a char array

Tags: c, linux, malloc, valgrind, memcpy

I am trying to split this char array into two parts first 4 character is one part rest is second part Its working but I get conditional jump issue on valgrind 
can any one advice the solution to this please

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    const char src[50] = "FLSZGRGR";
    char *dest1 = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(dest1, src, 4);
    printf("%s \n", dest1);
    if (strcmp(dest1, "FLSZ") == 0)
        printf("EQUAL 1 \n");

    char *dest2 = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(dest2, src + 4, 4);
    printf("%s \n", dest2);
    if (strcmp(dest2, "GRGR") == 0)
        printf("EQUAL 2 \n");

    free(dest1);
    free(dest2);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You don’t terminate the data in `dest1` or `dest2` and yet use string functions on them. Not ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems likely arise because your `dest1` and `dest2` strings are not *explicitily* `NUL`-terminated: the calls to `printf` (using the `%s` format) and `strcmp` **require** that the strings be `NUL`-terminated.

To fix this, you can either explicitly set the last `char` element to the `NUL` character:

```c
memcpy(dest1, src, 4);
dest1[4] = '\0'; // Explicitly set NUL terminator (do the same for "dest2")
```

or use `calloc` in place of `malloc` (which will set all elements to zero):

```c
char *dest1 = calloc(5, sizeof(char)); // And similarly for "dest2"
```

Without either of these, the memory allocated by the `malloc` calls will be *uninitialzed*, and you are entering the territory of **undefined behaviour**! The last elements of the `dest1` and `dest2` strings *may* be zero (which would make your code *seem* to work) but they may not be - in which case the `printf` and `strcmp` calls will keep looking, beyond the end of the allocated memory buffers, for the 'signal' `NUL` terminator.

Answer (score 4):

Here, you allocate 5 bytes of memory

```
char *dest1 = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
```

and here, you copy 4 bytes of your string into this buffer

```
memcpy(dest1, src, 4);
```

This means, that the remaining 5th byte is uninitialized. Now here

```
strcmp(dest1, "FLSZ")
```

you compare the buffer with the string "FLSZ". This is performed by comparing the first four characters byte by byte.

Then, `strcmp()` accesses the fifth byte, since the string is not terminated yet. However, this fifth byte is *not initialized*. It might be a zero byte by coincidence, causing the `strcmp()` to work, but valgrind detects the access of an uninitialized byte and complains, that a conditional branch/jump is based on uninitialized values.

You can fix this by zero-terminating the strings manually after you copied them.